# What causes vba application with backend MYSQL timing out

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

I have a front end database running on top of excel 2010 built on vba and using a back-end MYSQL database and this have been working fine since but just yesterday it started throwing errors like[image: error message]

any one with idea what might be causing this please help.I have tried all the possibilities running the queries again but no change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different types of isolation levels that exist in MySQL for your transactions : Read-Commited , Read-Uncommited , Deadlocks and so on.Probably there are 2 queries which have the isolation level that only if they are commited to run and they are blocking eachother going into a deadlock, maybe you have some queries which didn't ran in time and are still waiting to be commited, check your isolation levels. (Just a sugestion)